# How does the ternary operator work exactly works in with multiple coupled ternary operators?

Tags: pine-script

Please demonstrate how the ternary operator works with multiple ternary operators coupled to each other.
Example:

```
rngfilt = x > rngfilt[1] ? x - r < rngfilt[1] ? rngfilt[1] :
x - r : x + r > rngfilt[1] ? rngfilt[1] : x + r
```

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? Do you know how ternary operator works? Do you know about operator precedence? If the answer to both questions is yes, then combine your knowledge. To make precedence clear, its recommended to use explicit parenthesis, eventhough it's not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is common and is exactly why I avoid chaining ternary operators, even when I find them readable myself.

`condition1 ? yes : condition2 ? yes : condition3 ? yes : no`

If it helps, think of it as having parentheses:

`condition1 ? yes : (condition2 ? yes : (condition3 ? yes : no))`

The second expression is the "false" action for the first expression, and the third is the "false" action for the second. It would get even harder to follow if one ternary expression were the "true" action for another.